# ext4 to btrfs conversion: how many times the whole volume will be read during the process?

Tags: btrfs, benchmark

I want to convert the 3TB 80% full ext4 block device into btrfs and I want to estimate the time it will take. I understand that this process is disk-bound rather then cpu- or memory-bound. So can anyone explain me how long it will take *in units of time it takes to read/write the whole volume?*

Answer (score 1):

The whole process tool 5h25min, which is roughly 1⁄4 the time needed to re-balance the underlying RAID-5 mdadm device that span 5 modern 3TB SATA hard drives connected to two independent PCI-E controllers.